# How to cloak an email address in a custom html module in joomla 3.1?

Tags: email, joomla

is there a way to cloak an email address in a joomla (3.1) custom html module?
Simply entering the email address does neither hide it in the output, nor is the email address click-able.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enable the "Prepare Content" parameter in your module and the "Content - Email Cloaking" plugin, this should cloak your e-mail address.  Note that enabling this parameter in the module will parse it through all content plugins, which depending on which plugins you have installed, may cause unexpected results.

Answer (score 3):

If email is part of a content, use steps that Michael described.

When it's a separate entity (like parameter user fills in module configuration), use `Email: <?php echo JHtml::_('email.cloak', 'foo@bar.com', true) ?>`

See Joomla documentation: [How to cloak email addresses](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_cloak_email_addresses).

*Note: doesn't work on when output document is application/xhtml+xml, but that's a rare case.*